# Ring of rational functions for reducible variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition

Let $X$ be some affine algebraic variety over $\mathbb{k}$ (i.e. some closed subset in $\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{k}^n$). First suppose $X$ to be irreducible. Then the algebra $\mathbb{k}[X]$ is a domain and we can consider the field of rational functions $\mathrm{Quot}_{\mathbb{k}[X]}=\mathbb{k}(X)$. Could you explain me how to build an analogue of this field in the case when $X$ is not necessarily irreducible? Then $\mathbb{k}[X]$ must not be a domain and we are to build some kind of localization?
Also, what is the destination of rational functions? Why we cannot be satisfied with only regular maps and regular functions?

Answer (score 2):

The analogue of the quotient field for a ring with zero divisors is the [total ring of fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_quotient_ring): basically, just invert everything that is not a zero divisor. Geometrically, an element of this ring can be viewed as a collection of rational functions, one on each irreducible component of $X$, such that they coincide on intersections.

Rational functions are important for a wide variety of reasons. Asking this question is like asking why $\mathbf Q$ is important. Why weren't we happy with $\mathbf Z$? Well, it wasn't big enough for what we wanted to do, so we enlarged it.

Comment: Thank you, Bruno Joyal!
So, the rational function can be undefined at some points, isn't it? How we can describe the set where it can be defined?

Comment: You are welcome @Nikita. Well, they are defined: they take the value $\infty$. The points where they are finite could be called the "regular locus" or something like that. What kind of description would you like the set to have?

Comment: I meant the intersections of "regular locus" with irreducible components. In fact, I'd like to understand if the intersections can be empty...

Comment: @Nikita No, they cannot. I've added a precision to my post!

Comment: Could you explain this piece briefly?

Comment: @Well, we want our rational functions to be regular functions on some *nonempty* open set, because we want to be able to add them and multiply them. For this reason we exclude the case of a function which has a pole at every point.

Comment: I can't see what you mean. Did you mean that $f$ will have a pole at each $x\in X$, if it has a pole at each point of some irreducible component?

Comment: Dear Nikita and Bruno: except for $X$ of dimension one,  it is not true that a rational function on $X$ can be seen as a regular function from $X$ to $\mathbb P^1$ because of the points of indeterminacy for $f$. For example if $X=\mathbb A^2$ with coordinates $(x,y)$, the rational function $\frac xy$ has an indeterminacy point at $(0,0)$  and does not correspond to any morphism $X\to \mathbb P^1$ .

Comment: Thank you @Georges, you are absolutely right. I am used to smooth curves, and I am letting my guard down... :)

Answer (score 0):

This question may have general interest. There is an exercise in Matsumura (exercise 9.11 page 70) saying the following:

Let $A$ be a noetherian ring with the propery that $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is a domain for all prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}$. Let $\mathfrak{p}_1,..,\mathfrak{p}_l$ be the minimal prime ideals of $A$. It follows there is an isomorphism of rings

I1. $p:A \cong A/\mathfrak{p}_1\oplus \cdots \oplus A/\mathfrak{p}_l:=A_1\oplus \cdots \oplus A_l$

defined by

$p(a):=(\overline{a}, ..., \overline{a})$. This gives at the level of schemes an isomorphism

$Spec(A) \cong Spec(A_1) \cup \cdots \cup Spec(A_l)$

where the union is the "disjoint union".

This gives a general formula for the total ring of fractions $Tot(A)$:

I2. $Tot(A)\cong K(A/\mathfrak{p}_1)\oplus \cdots \oplus K(A/\mathfrak{p}_l)$

where $K(A/\mathfrak{p}_i)$ is the quotient field of the integral domain $A/\mathfrak{p}_i$.

Question: "Then k[X] must not be a domain and we are to build some kind of localization?"

Answer: The "total ring of fractions" is defined on page 21 in Matsumura's book "Commutative Ring Theory". This is a construction generalizing the "quotient field" defined for integral domains. If the ring $k[X]$ satisfies formula I1, it follows I2 gives a general formula for $Tot(k[X])$.

PS: I have not done the exercise myself.